# Using TeamViewer to connect to Windows Server VM instance in Google Compute Engine

Tags: virtual-machine, teamviewer, google-compute-engine

TeamViewer is installed in my Windows Server in GCE. For some reason, I can connect through TeamViewer only when I or another user is connected to the VM through Windows Remote Desktop. When the RDP session is terminated, TeamViewer says the remote computer is offline.

I've looked at the following pages:

https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/TeamViewer-on-Google-Cloud-Windows-Virtual-Machine-VM/td-p/30039

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/712266-remote-control-via-team-viewer-on-a-google-compute-vm-instace

TeamViewer on my server is set to start on Windows startup. I had restarted the VM to test the setting. Nothing has worked so far.

The idea is that users should be able to connect to the Windows server through TeamViewer without anyone having to connect to it through RDP. How can I make this work?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem today, and was able to solve it by uninstalling team viewer on the VM and then reinstalling it (the same version), this time running the installer as an adminstrator.